# jQuery $.post and cakePHP controller giving 400 bad request

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, post

I am trying to use $.post() to retrieve a json array from a cakePHP controller. I figured I would not need a view file as I will turn autorender to false and I am expecing a json array. I manage to get a response when I use $.ajax and $.get, but using $.post I get a 400 Bad Request.

My code:

```
$.post("controller/action",{id: "1"}, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
});

public function action() {
      $this->autoRender = false;
      $array = $_POST;
      header("Content-type: application/json");
      echo json_encode($array);
      exit;
}
```

Any help or tips on how to possibly do this better? As mentioned $.get, $.ajax does work, but the data callback does not return anything (but firebug shows response array).

Comment: This may be just a typo in your question but the `$.post` should be closed with `)` and I am certainly not a cakePHP expert - but I am pretty sure that `exit()` shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One error I see is, no indication to expect a json output.

```
$.post("controller/action",{id: "1"}, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
},"json");
```